# Weird gray gradient background appearing on mobile

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have a simple login form on a sliding modal. On desktop and in responsive mode with dev tools it looks as it should. However on mobile Chrome and Safari -- on an iphone, there's a weird gray rounded box or shadow.

I'm using tialwind css. And the component was built with headless ui.

I've tried adding `-webkit-appearance: none;` to the form, but the box still persits.

Here's how it looks on desktop:
[desktop view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyaFR.png)

and here is how it looks on my iphone:
[mobile view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5KaV.png)

here is the component code:

```js
return (
    <Transition.Root show={showModal.open} as={Fragment}>
      <Dialog
        as="div"
        className="fixed inset-0 overflow-hidden"
        onClose={() => setShowModal({ open: false })}
      >
        <div className="absolute inset-0 overflow-hidden">
          <Transition.Child
            as={Fragment}
            enter="ease-in-out duration-500"
            enterFrom="opacity-0"
            enterTo="opacity-100"
            leave="ease-in-out duration-500"
            leaveFrom="opacity-100"
            leaveTo="opacity-0"
          >
            <Dialog.Overlay className="absolute inset-0 bg-black bg-opacity-80 transition-opacity" />
          </Transition.Child>

          <div className="fixed inset-y-0 right-0 pl-10 max-w-full flex">
            <Transition.Child
              as={Fragment}
              enter="transform transition ease-in-out duration-500 sm:duration-700"
              enterFrom="translate-x-full"
              enterTo="translate-x-0"
              leave="transform transition ease-in-out duration-500 sm:duration-700"
              leaveFrom="translate-x-0"
              leaveTo="translate-x-full"
            >
              <div className="w-screen max-w-md">
                <div className="h-full flex flex-col py-6 bg-white shadow-xl overflow-y-scroll">
                  <div className="px-4 sm:px-6">
                    <div className="flex items-start justify-between">
                      <Dialog.Title className="text-2xl font-light text-vhGreen">
                        Welcome!
                      </Dialog.Title>
                      <div className="ml-3 h-7 flex items-center">
                        <button
                          type="button"
                          className="bg-white rounded-md text-vhGreen hover:text-gray-500 focus:outline-none"
                          onClick={() => setShowModal({ open: false })}
                        >
                          <span className="sr-only">Close panel</span>
                          <XCircleIcon className="h-6 w-6" aria-hidden="true" />
                        </button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="mt-6 relative flex-1 px-4 sm:px-6">
                    {/* Replace with your content */}
                    <div className="absolute inset-0 px-4 sm:px-6">
                      <div className="relative p-6 flex-auto bg-white">
                        <h4 className="text-vhGreen font-light">
                          Login or sign up to gain access to the gallery and to
                          receive periodic updates from Thea
                        </h4>
                        <form
                          type="submit"
                          onSubmit={(e) => handleSubmit(e)}
                          className="bg-white"
                        >
                          {isNewUser && (
                            <>
                              <div className="my-4 text-sm">
                                <label className="block text-vhGreen">
                                  First Name
                                </label>
                                <input
                                  value={authForm.firstName || ""}
                                  onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
                                  type="text"
                                  name="firstName"
                                  placeholder="First Name"
                                  className="w-full px-4 py-3 rounded-md text-vhGreen font-light"
                                />
                              </div>
                              <div className="my-4 text-sm">
                                <label className="block text-vhGreen">
                                  Last Name
                                </label>
                                <input
                                  value={authForm.lastName || ""}
                                  onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
                                  type="text"
                                  name="lastName"
                                  placeholder="Last Name"
                                  className="w-full px-4 py-3 rounded-md"
                                />
                              </div>
                            </>
                          )}
                          <div className="my-4 text-sm">
                            <label className="block text-vhGreen">Email</label>
                            <input
                              value={authForm.email || ""}
                              onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
                              type="text"
                              name="email"
                              placeholder="Email"
                              className="w-full px-4 py-3 rounded-md"
                            />
                          </div>
                          <div className="my-4 text-sm">
                            <label className="block text-vhGreen">
                              Password
                            </label>
                            <input
                              value={authForm.password || ""}
                              onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
                              type="password"
                              name="password"
                              placeholder="Password"
                              className="w-full px-4 py-3 rounded-md"
                              onKeyDown={(e) => onKeyDown(e)}
                            />
                            <div className="flex justify-end text-vhGreen text-sm font-light">
                              <button
                                type="button"
                                onClick={() => handleNewSwitch()}
                              >
                                {!isNewUser
                                  ? "Need an account? Sign Up!"
                                  : "Already have an account? Login!"}
                              </button>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </form>
                      </div>
                      {/*footer*/}
                      <div className="flex items-center justify-center p-6 border-t border-solid border-blueGray-200 rounded-b">
                        <button
                          className="text-vhGreen background-transparent font-light uppercase px-6 py-2 text-xl outline-none focus:outline-none mr-1 mb-1 ease-linear transition-all duration-150"
                          type="button"
                          onClick={(e) => handleSubmit(e)}
                        >
                          {isNewUser ? "Sign Up" : "Login"}
                        </button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    {/* /End replace */}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </Transition.Child>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Dialog>
    </Transition.Root>
  );
```

Comment: Same issue for me. Did you find an answer?

Answer (score 0):

faced same thing.

The problem is in:
type="button"

Try to remove that, works for me